# MySQL select query giving wrong sequences of rows from primary key

Tags: mysql

I am running this MySQL select query:

```
select * from ABC where column_value=1;
```

I expect to get output like this:

```
ID    Name
1     AAA
2     BBB
3     CCC
```

But instead I am getting this:

```
ID    Name
2     BBB
1     AAA
3     CCC
```

Can anyone give me an idea why MySQL is behaving like this?

Comment: Which column is denoted by `column_value`?

Comment: Use "order by" to get in inorder

Comment: Have you set your primary key as AUTO_INCREMENT? if not and if you have entered them manually, it might cause output like that.

Comment: @AbhrapratimNag yes "ID" column is AUTO_INCREMENTED and primary key

Answer (score 4):

Databases tend to use the fastest way to read data from tables. This means it may return data in any order if it finds it faster, unless you use an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Thanks. But my assumption that mysql will fetch data by primary key. Before this i got data correctly.

Comment: The `where column_value=1` may cause it to use a different index then primary key and the result may be different. You should never rely on order unless `ORDER BY` is used.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from ABC where column_value=1;
```

The query doesn't specify any sorting of the returned rows.

[SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) is a language that handle sets of tuples and [a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) is, by definition, an unordered collection of items.

The fact that, under some circumstances, one database engine or another returns the rows in a certain order (sorted by the value of the `PK` f.e.) is an implementation detail. It is not required by the language and it can change any time.

Even more, when the query doesn't specify an order for the returned rows, the database engine uses whatever method it finds more appropriate to get them fast. The order may depend on external factors and it may change over time. For example, if you remove from the table the rows returned by the query then insert them again but in a different order, a subsequent run of the same query may (and it most probably does) return the rows in a different order than before.

As an insight (that is neither exact, nor reliable), for a query that doesn't contain an `ORDER BY` clause over a small table, the database returns the rows in the order it finds them in the table data because it doesn't read the index.

For small tables the engine skips reading the index when it is not needed and goes directly to the table data. This way it spares a disk access that doesn't provide any additional value to the processing.

Answer (score 0):

By default id ie. default primary key will be used for "order by", might be possible that you have deleted some rows?

Comment: ID is primary key. so deleting records will effect insert/selection order

Comment: yes, if you are not giving any order by it will be on ID and updates/deletes might affect expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from ABC order by ID where column_value=1;
```

You can use `order by` feature to obtain the desired result.